# Print 10 characters before a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to print a string that usually comes before another string, for example `"12/07/201911 : 00Type of Occurrence"`. Here I'm trying to print the time `"11 : 00"` which always come before the text `"Type of Occurrence"`.

I have tried this which print everything before the identifier. I would like to only print 7 characters before the identifier.

```
import re
A="12/07/2019 11 : 00Type of Occurrence"
print(A.split('Type of Occurrence', 1)[0].replace('.', '').upper())
```

It prints :

```
12/07/2019 11 : 00
```

Comment: You may use: `(.{7})Type of Occurrence` in `re.findall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
A="12/07/2019 11 : 00Type of Occurrence"
print(" ".join(A.split("Type of Occurrence")[0].split()[1:]))
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
11 : 00
```

Process :

1. `A.split("Type of Occurrence")[0]` gives `"12/07/2019 11 : 00"`
2. `"12/07/2019 11 : 00".split()[1:]` gives `['11', ':', '00']`
3. `" ".join(['11', ':', '00'])` gives `11 : 00`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
>>> A="12/07/2019 11 : 00Type of Occurrence"
>>> i = A.find('Type of Occurrence')
>>> i
18
>>> A[i-7:i]
'11 : 00'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the whitespaces between the colon can vary, you might use a capturing group for the time part and match Type of Occurrence:

```
((?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])\s*:\s*[0-5][0-9])Type of Occurrence
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O6XxYf/1)

Answer (score 0):

Basic Idea:

```
A="12/07/2019 11 : 00Type of Occurrence"

A = A.split('Type of Occurrence', 1)[0].replace('.', '').upper()
A[-7:]
>>> '11 : 00'
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to only print 7 characters before the identifier.

You may use this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> A="12/07/2019 11 : 00Type of Occurrence"
>>> print re.findall(r'(.{7})Type of Occurrence', A)[0]
11 : 00
```

`re.findall` prints captured group if they are available in regex.